A persistent kv to disk with a Go map[string]string
My needs: a simple map[string]string in a Go application, that needs to be persisted to disk. I don't want to use a database, a json file could be enough, writes are rare and no parallelism is needed.
The content of the data:
{
"something"      : "35b7bd1e-0eab-11ef-8a72-ef7c0dade844",
"something else" : "35b7bdf0-0eab-11ef-8a73-67ce44126d91" 
}

The basic operation with the data is:
looking up for a string, if exists return the UUID, otherwise insert it, generate a new uuid, and returns.
I have tried to use jsonfile, but is not clear to me how to use Write inside a Read
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "crawshaw.dev/jsonfile"
)

type Data struct {
    Identifiers map[string]string `json:"identifiers"`
}


func main() {
    db, err := jsonfile.Load[Data]("resolver.json")
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        db, err = jsonfile.New[Data]("resolver.json")
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    db.Read(func(d *Data) {
        v, ok := d.Identifiers["MISSING-KEY"]
        if !ok {
            //
            // HOW TO ADD THE MISSING KEY?
            //
        } else {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    })


}


Why not use Go encoding/json's Marshal/Unmarshal and read/write the output from/to a json file?

Asking for libs is off-topic. There are countless libs to do this (e.g. github.com/icza/kvcache disclosure: I'm the author).

sorry for asking for a lib (but thanks for the link). my question remains related to the use of crawshaw.dev/jsonfile

You can't write inside a read. Make them separate:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/fs"
    "log"

    "crawshaw.dev/jsonfile"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Data struct {
    Identifiers map[string]string `json:"identifiers"`
}

const (
    dbPath     = "resolver.json"
    missingKey = "MISSING-KEY"
)

func main() {
    db, err := jsonfile.Load[Data](dbPath)
    if errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist) {
        db, err = jsonfile.New[Data](dbPath)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = readWrite(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func readWrite(db *jsonfile.JSONFile[Data]) error {
    var (
        v         string
        keyExists bool
    )

    db.Read(func(d *Data) {
        v, keyExists = d.Identifiers[missingKey]
    })

    if keyExists {
        fmt.Println(v)
        return nil
    }

    v = uuid.NewString()

    return db.Write(func(d *Data) error {
        if d.Identifiers == nil {
            d.Identifiers = make(map[string]string)
        }
        d.Identifiers[missingKey] = v

        return nil
    })
}

Note that this might have a minor race condition - when two tasks read the same file with a missing key, the second overwrites the key of the first. I could check in db.Write if the key already exists, but given your use case I didn't bother.
